# Select first row in each group using group by in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, group-by

I have a table in sqlite. I am trying to get the first row of each group. Although there were earlier questions regarding the same. I couldn't find solution in sqlite.

My table looks like this:

```
select * from geoview
MaxOfStatecountpercent | statepoolnumber | STATECODE
123                       1234              CA
123                       1234              FL
234                       1678              TX
234                       1678              MN
234                       0987              FL
234                       0987              CA
234                       9876              TX
```

I would like to query the first of MaxOfStatecountpercent and first of STATECODE from each statepoolnumber. The equivalent access sql query is :

```
select first(MaxOfStatecountpercent), statepoolnumber, first(STATECODE) from geoview group by statepoolnumber;
```

And the output expected is :

```
First(MaxOfStatecountpercent) | statepoolnumber | First(STATECODE)
123                             1234              CA
234                             1678              TX
234                             0987              FL
234                             9876              TX
```

I tried with "limit 1 " but did not work. How can i get a query equivalent in sqlite?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The following works for me with your sample table data:

```
SELECT MaxOfStatecountpercent, statepoolnumber, STATECODE
FROM geoview
GROUP BY statepoolnumber
HAVING MIN(ROWID)
ORDER BY ROWID
```

This assumes that, based on your desired input, you want the 'first' state of each statepoolnumber group to be the first record (rather than 'first' by alphabetical order).

Comment: `HAVING MIN(ROWID)` does not work if the rowid is zero.

Comment: Instead of `HAVING MIN(ROWID)`, use `HAVING ROWID = MIN(ROWID)`.

Comment: Is there a reference or documentation supporting the `HAVING ROWID = MIN(ROWID)`? Is it more performant than using a window function?